# How do I make sure on_stop runs in a pipeline if the step using the keyword fails?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a step in a pipeline that creates a MR environment and then when the MR is merged tears down the MR environment using the `on_stop` keyword.

*Example step*

```yaml
deploy-mr-env:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - helm/config/values-sandbox.yml
  extends:
    - .deploy-mr-env-base
  variables:
    HELM_SANDBOX_CONFIGS: >-
      -f helm/config/values-sandbox.yml
      -f helm/config/secrets-sandbox.yml
  environment:
    name: ${MR_ENVIRONMENT}
    url: https://${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-mr${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}.sandbox.com
    on_stop: stop-mr-env
```

The bug we found with our pipeline looks like this:

- A MR is created and a MR environment is stood up.
- Changes are made based on what is discovered with the MR env deployment.
- A change is pushed to MR branch (kicking off the pipeline) prior to the MR being merged, some anomalous event occurs on the cloud platform used to host the MR env, and the `deploy-mr-env` step fails (i.e. - `oc login` command fails for some weird reason).
- MR is merged.
- Because `deploy-mr-env` failed when the last changes were pushed to MR branch `on_stop` doesn't run.

Normally `on_stop` runs when a MR is merged, but this is a weird little edge case in our pipeline. How would we make sure `on_stop` runs during a merge event even if the `deploy-mr-env` step failed the previous time changes were pushed to the MR branch?

Comment: `on_stop` only applies to _successful_ deployments. If your deploy job failed, then your stop won't trigger in this case. Consider setting `allow_failure: true` to your deployment job and see if that helps.

Comment: @sytech I had considered this. I also considered introducing some retry logic to get around the anomalous events that occasionally occur. My worry is that it would introduce unwanted behavior in the pipeline to address this event that only occurs rarely.